# Gaps appearing in an email in only Android Gmail. How do I fix this issue?

Tags: android, html, email, gmail, html-email

I have an email that works perfectly in all email clients (the Outlooks, iOS, Litmus etc) except the Gmail App on Android.

In that app it has gaps appear in it. This is a screenshot of the issue, this is just a basic proof of concept:

[image]

Some HTML is below, the issue happens with nested tables in table cells (td). So this has a set of tables and cells with images inside that are the same size of their cell.

Here is a jsfiddle of the html: http://jsfiddle.net/cntdsp5p/

And here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html style="margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body{ margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; }
    body{ background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; font-family:sans-serif; }
    table{ margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; }
    a img{ color:#000001 !important; }

.wysiwyg-text-align-right{ text-align: right; }
.wysiwyg-text-align-center { text-align: center; }
.wysiwyg-text-align-left{ text-align: left; }
.wysiwyg-text-align-justify{ text-align: justify; }

body{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; line-height:24px; }

h1{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-weight:400; font-family:Arial; font-size:36px; line-height:44px; }

h2{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-weight:400; font-family:Arial; font-size:24px; line-height:32px; }

h3{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-weight:400; font-family:Arial; font-size:15px; line-height:21px; }

p{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; line-height:24px; }

a{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#1122CC !important; text-decoration:underline; }




        .mi-all{ display: block; }
        .mi-desktop{ display: block; }

    .mi-mobile{
        display: none;
        font-size: 0; 
        max-height: 0; 
        line-height: 0; 
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        mso-hide: all; /* hide elements in Outlook 2007-2013 */
    }


</style>

<style type="text/css" >

    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (max-width: 480px), screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 630px) {

        /* very important! all except 'all' and this current type get a display:none; */
        .mi-desktop{ display: none !important; }

        /* then show the mobile one */
        .mi-mobile{ 
            display: block !important;
            font-size: 12px !important;
            max-height: none !important;
            line-height: 1.5 !important;
            float: none !important;
            overflow: visible !important;
        }
    }

</style>


   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>
<body style="background: #FFFFFF; color: #000000 !important; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; margin: 0px 0 0 0px; padding: 0px 0 0; text-shadow: none" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important;
}
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
text-shadow: none; padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; color: #000000 !important; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px;
}
</style>
<!-- admin --><div class="mi-desktop" style="display: block">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tbody>
            <tr align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none">
                <td valign="top" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none">
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
                        <tbody>
                                <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none">
                                    <td width="100%">
                                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none">
                                                    <td width="100%">
                                                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0; height: 50px">
<td width="100%" valign="top" height="50" align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img width="1" height="50" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 1; opacity: 0; padding: 0px" src="http://mailrox-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/clear.gif" alt=""></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin: 0px 0 0; padding: 0px 0 0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">

<div class="mi-all" style="display: block">
    <table class="mi-all" width="566" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; display: block; margin: 0px 0 0; padding: 0px 0 0">
        <tbody>
                <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="566">
            <table width="566" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="566" height="117" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218755/490d09a47432a346ff8b0e78081c0893-original.jpg?1423832407" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="566">
            <table width="566" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="62" height="208" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218759/19ddd566053aea03ffa236be1c3c7106-original.jpg?1423832410" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                            <td width="437" align="left" valign="top">
    <table width="437" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin: 0px 0 0; padding: 0px 0 0">
        <tbody> <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="437">
            <table width="437" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="437" height="75" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218763/34af46b5e9b769c00b2ecdb0e18fb2f6-original.jpg?1423832414" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="437">
            <table width="437" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="96" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218767/bd9eaee611c770ba4e1cf622dc3a8c2d-original.jpg?1423832418" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                            <td width="52" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218769/45fec80922c3f48137c596c3ff749dfb-original.jpg?1423832419" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                            <td width="83" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218771/b47339b9fc571427b652bddc8ff27308-original.jpg?1423832420" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                            <td width="40" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218773/82abd90c62a69a367df080c998d95921-original.jpg?1423832422" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                            <td width="42" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218775/bdc152f96b37a54241d4148d49370f3b-original.jpg?1423832423" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                            <td width="41" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218777/6c5cecb72d86a5fd28304bc2d3c2251d-original.jpg?1423832425" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                            <td width="83" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218778/1765f64e482ae6f647ac92dca014d991-original.jpg?1423832425" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="437">
            <table width="437" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="437" height="84" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218766/674169b8b96dea256dd794836c855230-original.jpg?1423832416" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
</td>

                            <td width="67" height="208" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218762/425f7c48b0e4215a8f3109dc03927e76-original.jpg?1423832412" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="566">
            <table width="566" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="566" height="185" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218758/8eb37cb41486fd5f0528650bea1fe398-original.jpg?1423832409" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>



  </body>
</html>
```

Again this email works perfectly in everything except the Android Gmail app, I'd love to know how to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Giving your tables `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: none;"` and your images `style="display: block;"` is certainly a good start, but sadly the gmail android app does some extra-strange things with image sizes. It relates to how the app attempts to make the e-mail fit on your screen (you may notice differences between portrait and landscape mode).

---

**Solution to horizontal gaps (between cols):**

To fix the horizontal gaps you can give your images an inline style of `width: 100%;` while giving the parent `<td>` elements `min-width:--px;`. You may even get away with just the min-width declaration if you put it on the right element.

---

**Solution to vertical gaps (between rows):**

This will then leave you with two vertical gaps, one of which is easily taken care of by giving all of your images their width and height attributes. Always make sure to **give all fixed-size images an explicit width and height.**

The second vertical gap is harder to deal with. This one seems to appear when you nest a table with multiple rows of images inside of a cell whos siblings have no such nested tables. [Here is another example of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27784834/2126792). *At the moment I do not have a solution to this type of gap... I will post here if I find or come up with one.*

**Edit:**

I have found what appears to be a workaround solution [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/Fxt78gN5q5E), however, I have had no luck implementing it. Maybe you will have better luck, but you may have to change your HTML structure for it to work. To sum up the workaround:

> Restating the problem - Gmail app rounds up when resizing tables, and down when resizing images. This can cause a 1 pixel gap appear between images on a table.

1. Give all `<tr>`s an inline style of `display: block; white-space: nowrap;`.
2. Give all `<td>`s an inline style of `display: inline-block;`.
3. Remove any width or height declarations from your `<td>`s including the `min-width` style that we added to fix the horizontal gaps (should no longer be necessary).
4. Remove any whitespace between your `<td>`s.
5. Ensure that your container table has a `min-width`.

[Campaign Monitor's CSS Guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) may also be of use to you while troubleshooting this issue.

---

**Here is your code with my first modifications (one vertical gap, no workaround):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html style="margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body{ margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; }
    body{ background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; font-family:sans-serif; }
    table{ margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; }
    a img{ color:#000001 !important; }

.wysiwyg-text-align-right{ text-align: right; }
.wysiwyg-text-align-center { text-align: center; }
.wysiwyg-text-align-left{ text-align: left; }
.wysiwyg-text-align-justify{ text-align: justify; }

body{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; line-height:24px; }

h1{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-weight:400; font-family:Arial; font-size:36px; line-height:44px; }

h2{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-weight:400; font-family:Arial; font-size:24px; line-height:32px; }

h3{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-weight:400; font-family:Arial; font-size:15px; line-height:21px; }

p{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#000000 !important; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; line-height:24px; }

a{ text-shadow:none; padding-top:0; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:0; margin-top:0; margin-right:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; color:#1122CC !important; text-decoration:underline; }




        .mi-all{ display: block; }
        .mi-desktop{ display: block; }

    .mi-mobile{
        display: none;
        font-size: 0; 
        max-height: 0; 
        line-height: 0; 
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        mso-hide: all; /* hide elements in Outlook 2007-2013 */
    }


</style>

<style type="text/css" >

    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (max-width: 480px), screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 630px) {

        /* very important! all except 'all' and this current type get a display:none; */
        .mi-desktop{ display: none !important; }

        /* then show the mobile one */
        .mi-mobile{ 
            display: block !important;
            font-size: 12px !important;
            max-height: none !important;
            line-height: 1.5 !important;
            float: none !important;
            overflow: visible !important;
        }
    }

</style>


   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>
<body style="background: #FFFFFF; color: #000000 !important; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; margin: 0px 0 0 0px; padding: 0px 0 0; text-shadow: none" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important;
}
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
text-shadow: none; padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; color: #000000 !important; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px;
}
</style>
<!-- admin --><div class="mi-desktop" style="display: block">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tbody>
            <tr align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none">
                <td valign="top" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none">
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
                        <tbody>
                                <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none">
                                    <td width="100%">
                                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none">
                                                    <td width="100%">
                                                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0px none; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; border: 0; height: 50px">
<td width="100%" valign="top" height="50" align="left" style="background: #FFFFFF" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img width="1" height="50" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 1; opacity: 0; padding: 0px" src="http://mailrox-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/clear.gif" alt=""></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="background: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin: 0px 0 0; padding: 0px 0 0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">

<div class="mi-all" style="display: block">
    <table class="mi-all" width="566" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; display: block; margin: 0px 0 0; padding: 0px 0 0">
        <tbody>
                <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="566">
            <table width="566" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="566" height="117" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218755/490d09a47432a346ff8b0e78081c0893-original.jpg?1423832407" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="566">
            <table width="566" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="62" height="208" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;min-width:62px;">



            <img width="62" height="208" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218759/19ddd566053aea03ffa236be1c3c7106-original.jpg?1423832410" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px;width:100%;">



</td>

                            <td width="437" align="left" valign="top">
    <table width="437" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin: 0px 0 0; padding: 0px 0 0">
        <tbody> <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="437">
            <table width="437" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="437" height="75" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img width="437" height="75" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218763/34af46b5e9b769c00b2ecdb0e18fb2f6-original.jpg?1423832414" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="437">
            <table width="437" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="96" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;min-width: 96px;">



            <img width="96" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218767/bd9eaee611c770ba4e1cf622dc3a8c2d-original.jpg?1423832418" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td>

                            <td width="52" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;min-width: 52px;">



            <img width="52" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218769/45fec80922c3f48137c596c3ff749dfb-original.jpg?1423832419" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td>

                            <td width="83" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;min-width: 83px;">



            <img width="83" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218771/b47339b9fc571427b652bddc8ff27308-original.jpg?1423832420" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td>

                            <td width="40" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;min-width: 40px;">



            <img width="40" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218773/82abd90c62a69a367df080c998d95921-original.jpg?1423832422" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td>

                            <td width="42" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;min-width: 42px;">



            <img width="42" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218775/bdc152f96b37a54241d4148d49370f3b-original.jpg?1423832423" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td>

                            <td width="41" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;min-width: 41px;">



            <img width="41" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218777/6c5cecb72d86a5fd28304bc2d3c2251d-original.jpg?1423832425" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td>

                            <td width="83" height="49" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;min-width: 83px;">



            <img width="83" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218778/1765f64e482ae6f647ac92dca014d991-original.jpg?1423832425" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="437">
            <table width="437" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="437" height="84" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img width="437" height="84" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218766/674169b8b96dea256dd794836c855230-original.jpg?1423832416" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
</td>

                            <td width="67" height="208" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;min-width: 67px;">



            <img width="67" height="208" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218762/425f7c48b0e4215a8f3109dc03927e76-original.jpg?1423832412" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
        <td width="566">
            <table width="566" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td width="566" height="185" align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly">



            <img src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218758/8eb37cb41486fd5f0528650bea1fe398-original.jpg?1423832409" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>



  </body>
</html>
```

---

**And here your code with my attempt at implementing the workaround (table only):**

```
<table width="437" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; min-width: 437px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr style="display: block; white-space: nowrap; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; border: 0">
                            <td align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;display: inline-block;">



            <img width="96" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218767/bd9eaee611c770ba4e1cf622dc3a8c2d-original.jpg?1423832418" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;display: inline-block;">



            <img width="52" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218769/45fec80922c3f48137c596c3ff749dfb-original.jpg?1423832419" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;display: inline-block;">



            <img width="83" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218771/b47339b9fc571427b652bddc8ff27308-original.jpg?1423832420" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;display: inline-block;">



            <img width="40" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218773/82abd90c62a69a367df080c998d95921-original.jpg?1423832422" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;display: inline-block;">



            <img width="42" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218775/bdc152f96b37a54241d4148d49370f3b-original.jpg?1423832423" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;display: inline-block;">



            <img width="41" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218777/6c5cecb72d86a5fd28304bc2d3c2251d-original.jpg?1423832425" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td><td align="left" valign="top" style="line-height: 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;display: inline-block;">



            <img width="83" height="49" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218778/1765f64e482ae6f647ac92dca014d991-original.jpg?1423832425" style="border: 0; display: block; line-height: 0px; width: 100%;">



</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not identify the exact issue, but reviewing the code, there's a lot of declarations not needed and/or doing double work. I think that there may be some contradictions there. I've re-created your HTML (https://jsfiddle.net/edu8rdo/bp5kmgbp/) and ran a Litmus test on it, seeing no gaps in the Gmail.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charSet=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ReadMsgBody{ width: 100%;}
            #outlook a { padding:0; }
            body{ width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; } 
            .ExternalClass { width:100%;}
            .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; }
            #backgroundTable { margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}

            img { outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; } 
            a img { border:none; } 

            p { margin: 1em 0; }

            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { color: black !important; }
            h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { color: blue !important; }

            table td { border-collapse: collapse; }
            table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }

            @-ms-viewport{
                width: device-width;
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            html,body {
                width: 100%;
                overflow-x: hidden; 
            }
            body[yahoo] .container {
                width:100% !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .mobile_image {
                width:100% !important;
                height:auto !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .drop {
                width:100% !important;
                display:block !important;
            }
            body[yahoo] .hide_this {
                display:none !important;
            }
        }
        </style>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <style>
                /* Target Outlook 2007 and 2010 */
            </style>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px; padding:0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none;" yahoo="fix">
    <!--Email_start-->
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218755/490d09a47432a346ff8b0e78081c0893-original.jpg?1423832407" width="566" height="177" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218759/19ddd566053aea03ffa236be1c3c7106-original.jpg?1423832410" width="62" height="208" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218763/34af46b5e9b769c00b2ecdb0e18fb2f6-original.jpg?1423832414" width="437" height="75" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                            <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218767/bd9eaee611c770ba4e1cf622dc3a8c2d-original.jpg?1423832418" width="96" height="49" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                            <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218769/45fec80922c3f48137c596c3ff749dfb-original.jpg?1423832419" width="52" height="49" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                            <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218771/b47339b9fc571427b652bddc8ff27308-original.jpg?1423832420" width="83" height="49" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                            <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218773/82abd90c62a69a367df080c998d95921-original.jpg?1423832422" width="40" height="49" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                            <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218775/bdc152f96b37a54241d4148d49370f3b-original.jpg?1423832423" width="42" height="49" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                            <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218777/6c5cecb72d86a5fd28304bc2d3c2251d-original.jpg?1423832425" width="41" height="49" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                            <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218778/1765f64e482ae6f647ac92dca014d991-original.jpg?1423832425" width="83" height="49" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                                <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218766/674169b8b96dea256dd794836c855230-original.jpg?1423832416" width="437" height="84" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                                <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218762/425f7c48b0e4215a8f3109dc03927e76-original.jpg?1423832412" width="67" height="208" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                        <img alt="" src="http://mailrox2-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/crops/3218758/8eb37cb41486fd5f0528650bea1fe398-original.jpg?1423832409" width="566" height="185" border="0" style="display: block;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
    <!--Email_end-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Those we're needed declarations, now the email does not work in: Lotus Notes 6.5, Lotus Notes 7, Lotus Notes 8.5, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2007, Outlook 2013.

Answer (score -1):

Set on your table this

```
<table ..... style="font-size : 0px">
```